# small object detection with faster-RCNN in tensorflow-models

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm attempting to train a faster-rccn model for small digit detection. I'm using the newly released tensorflow [object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) and so far have been fine tuning a pre-trained [faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) from the zoo. All my training attempts have resulted in models with high precision but low recall. Out of the ~120 objects (digits) on each image only ~20 objects are ever detected, but when detected the classification is accurate. (Also, I am able to train a simple convnet from scratch on my cropped images with high accuracy so the problem is in the detection aspect of the model.) Each digit is on average 60x30 in the original images (and probably about half that size after the image is resized before being fed into the model.) Here is an example image with detected boxes of what I'm seeing:
[image]

What is odd to me is how it is able to correctly detect neighboring digits but completely miss the rest that are very similar in terms of pixel dimensions.

I have tried adjusting the hyperparameters around anchor box generation and `first_stage_max_proposals` but nothing has improved the results so far. Here is an example [config](https://gist.github.com/bmabey/4ed76b74484376df97d29e0c52d8a45d) file I have used. What other hyperparameters should I try adjusting? Any other suggestions on how to diagnose the problem? Should I be looking into other [architectures](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~peiyunh/tiny/) or does my task look doable with faster-rccn and/or SSD?

Comment: Hi Ben - what are typical image resolutions for your dataset?

Comment: Also note that in the visualizer (`visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`) we let the max number of boxes default to 20 and the min score threshold to default to 0.5 --- you have to override these explicitly if you want to be more permissive.

Comment: Right now the majority of my images are 3264 × 2248, which is the dimension of an iPhone image (from a iPhone 6 at least). Thanks for the pointer on the visualizer, I'll check into that.

Comment: Jonathan - thanks again for the `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` tip. I had been lazy and was using the visualizer to spot check things before looking at the actual predictions. For easy images (like above) detection seems to be working well, the classification is poor though. (Images with different perspectives still have a low detection rate.) I have some ideas to try to address these issues though. Thanks!

Comment: First link seems broken...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end the immediate problem was that I was not using the visualizer correctly. By updating the parameters for `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` as described by Johnathan in the comments I was able to see that that I am at least detecting more boxes than I had thought.

Comment: Except for being able to see more bounding boxes, have your model improved on finding small objects? I am working on detect small objects (55 by 15 pix) on big images (1920 by 1080). I have hard time finding anything on my images after training (I have tried all the pre-trained models, none of them produced good results), which is similar to the image you showed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I check your config gile, you are decreasing the resolution of your image to 1024. The region of your digit will not contain a lot of pixel and you are loosing some information. What I suggest is to train the model with an another dataset (smaller images). You can for example crop the images in 4 four area.

If you have a good GPU increase the max dimension in the image_resizer, but I guess you will run out of memory